# Semantic UI dynamic dropdown reinitialize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I use semantic UI dropdown plugin. active the plugin on load by

```
$(function () {
   $('select.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

in my code there is two dropdown one's date is dependen on other. on change first dropdown I populate other's value.

```
$('.city').on('change', function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id != '') {
        $.get('ajax/town/' + id).done(function (result) {
            var div = '';
            $.each(result, function (i, e) {
                div += '<option value="' + e.id + '">' + e.town + '</option>';
            });
            $('.town').html(div);
            $('select.dropdown.town').dropdown('refresh');
        });
    }
});
```

But the dropdown doesnot reinitialize, but show a list in a div. How to solve this issue.

Comment: what do you mean by `reinit`?

Comment: sorry reinitialize

Comment: Could you please provide some `demo`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved. by changing...

```
$('.town').html(div);
$('select.dropdown.town').dropdown('refresh');
```

to

```
$('.town select').html(div).dropdown();
```